# Unpickle file from HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm currently using Python 3 and would like to load a pickle file out of HDFS.

```
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
import pickle

hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='...', user_name='...')
pickled_model = hdfs.read_file(pickle_path)
model = pickle.load(pickled_model)

TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

I get a type error at the pickle loading stage. I found an option to open the file using `pydoop` and then unpickle it. But unfortunately, I can't use Python 2.7. Any similar options?

Comment: pickle.load expects an actual python filehandler. I'm not sure what type hdfs.read_file returns but for loading memory to pickle there is a method called pickle.loads(bytes) as far as i remember.

Comment: @BluBb_mADe Perfect. I overly complicated it for sure.

Comment: @justin can you please suggest how to store the model to hdfs by using pickle option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per BluBb, `pickle.load` requires a Python FileHandler. `hdfs.read_file` returns bytes in this case and using `pickle.loads` read the model properly.

Comment: how to write the python model to hdfs using pickle function

Comment: The above answer is for loading a model, how to store the model in hdfs

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar I used the PyWebHdfsClient library along with Pickle. `model_pickle = pickle.dumps(model)` pickles the model. Then `hdfs.create_file(path, model_pickle, overwrite=True)` will write the `model_pickle` into `path` and `hdfs` is a PyWebHdfsClient instance.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar These will help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps and https://pythonhosted.org/pywebhdfs/