# How to read .pkl file using python in hdfs

Tags: python, hdfs

I'm using Python 3.5.2 in IBM cloud. I need to run a pyspark code in cluster environment. For this work I need to upload pickle file in hdfs using python. I saw the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766722/unpickle-file-from-hdfs)

I want to upload terrs.pkl. The file location is given in attached screen shot [image]

I'm using following command as per the suggestion given in the link that I shared

```
pickle.load( open( '/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl', "rb" ) )
```

But it's throwing error that

```
No such file or directory: '/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl'
```

Please refer the attached screen shot. 
[image]
Can you suggest me how do I load this .pkl file using python?

Comment: When you do `import os` and `os.path.exists('/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl')` do you get True or False?

Comment: I'm getting False

Comment: That means the file is not on that location or that there is a typo in your path name. Your pickle code calls are correct. Make sure your file exists in that exact location.

Answer (score 0):

```
open_file = open("/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl", "rb")
data = pickle.load(open_file)
open_file.close()
```

Comment: in Open file statement also I'm getting error message FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl'

Comment: Try to add the absolute path. What is the OS that you are using ?

Comment: I'm trying to connect IBM Cloud from my windows 10.I'm using git tool to connect IBM Cloud

Comment: What's the difference between what you suggested and what @EmilyJohnson tried?
`pickle.load( open( '/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl', "rb" ) )`
is same as
`open_file = open("/user/clsadmin/terrs.pkl", "rb")`
`data = pickle.load(open_file)`